# Anyway to detect if a file/executable is ran?

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I downloaded a file and ran it, is there a way to make the application detect and print out (Console.WriteLine) the full path of the executable?

Comment: if you know the name of the executable you can create a loop to check if the process is running and notify

Comment: I want it to be any executable, not a specific name

Comment: So you *downloaded a file and ran it*, but you don't know the path you ran it from? How come?

Comment: I assume this is not your actual scenario. If you want to detect when a Process is run and/or terminated, you can use WMI events.

Comment: Let's say a file scanning for malicious files, one of the ways it starts a scan is when a file is ran